# Single and multiple files

Tags: javascript, performance

I have recently received some feedback on a project I did called [Notifier.js](https://github.com/rlemon/Notifier.js), in which you can see I have included all of the source images and styles in the JavaScript file. The feedback I received was that having it all bundled up together may be *cool*, but it is in fact not as performant and harder to maintain (which, if you know JS and CSS is not true... but that is to be debated later).

My reasoning for doing the script this way was two parts:

1. fewer requests
2. single file include means no mucking about with "*where did I store the images, ohh now I have to alter the CSS file... and the JS file..*" kind of business.. the KISS principal (*Keep It Simple, Stupid!*).

Have I in fact taken the wrong approach? Are the downfalls of doing it my way worse than the benefits? I can't see how it would be *that* much slower just to load the base64 images and style the elements with JS (am I wrong?).

While you are looking, any other feedback would be greatly appreciated.

```
var Notifier = (function() {
    var apply_styles = function(element, style_object) {
        for (var prop in style_object) {
            element.style[prop] = style_object[prop];
        }
    };
    var fade_out = function(element) {
        if (element.style.opacity && element.style.opacity > 0.05) {
            element.style.opacity = element.style.opacity - 0.05;
        } else if (element.style.opacity && element.style.opacity <= 0.1) {
            if (element.parentNode) {
                element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
            }
        } else {
            element.style.opacity = 0.9;
        }
        setTimeout(function() {
            fade_out.apply(this, [element]);
        }, 1000 / 30);
    };
    var config = { /* How long the notification stays visible */
        default_timeout: 5000,
        /* container for the notifications */
        container: document.createElement('div'),
        /* container styles for notifications */
        container_styles: {
            position: "fixed",
            zIndex: 99999,
            right: "12px",
            top: "12px"
        },
        /* individual notification box styles */
        box_styles: {
            cursor: "pointer",
            padding: "12px 18px",
            margin: "0 0 6px 0",
            backgroundColor: "#000",
            opacity: 0.8,
            color: "#fff",
            font: "normal 13px 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif",
            borderRadius: "3px",
            boxShadow: "#999 0 0 12px",
            width: "300px"
        },
        /* individual notification box hover styles */
        box_styles_hover: {
            opacity: 1,
            boxShadow: "#000 0 0 12px"
        },
        /* notification title text styles */
        title_styles: {
            fontWeight: "700"
        },
        /* notification body text styles */
        text_styles: {
            display: "inline-block",
            verticalAlign: "middle",
            width: "240px",
            padding: "0 12px"
        },
        /* notification icon styles */
        icon_styles: {
            display: "inline-block",
            verticalAlign: "middle",
            height: "36px",
            width: "36px"
        }
    };
    apply_styles(config.container, config.container_styles);
    document.body.appendChild(config.container);
    return {
        notify: function(message, title, image) {

            var notification = document.createElement('div');
            apply_styles(notification, config.box_styles);

            notification.onmouseover = function() {
                apply_styles(this, config.box_styles_hover);
            };
            notification.onmouseout = function() {
                apply_styles(this, config.box_styles);
            };
            notification.onclick = function() {
                this.style.display = 'none';
            };

            var icon = document.createElement('img');
            icon.src = image;
            apply_styles(icon, config.icon_styles);

            notification.appendChild(icon);

            var text = document.createElement('div');
            apply_styles(text, config.text_styles);

            notification.appendChild(text);

            if (title) {
                var title_text = document.createElement('div');
                apply_styles(title_text, config.title_styles);
                title_text.appendChild(document.createTextNode(title));
                text.appendChild(title_text);
            }

            if (message) {
                var message_text = document.createElement('div');
                message_text.appendChild(document.createTextNode(message));
                text.appendChild(message_text);
            }

            config.container.insertBefore(notification, config.container.firstChild);

            setTimeout(function() {
                fade_out(notification);
            }, config.default_timeout);
        },
        info: function(message, title) {
            this.notify(message, title, "data:image/png;base64,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");
        },
        warning: function(message, title) {
            this.notify(message, title, "data:image/png;base64,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");
        },
        success: function(message, title) {
            this.notify(message, title, "data:image/png;base64,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");
        },
        error: function(message, title) {
            this.notify(message, title, "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAAgCAYAAABzenr0AAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAAZiS0dEAP8A/wD/oL2nkwAAAAlwSFlzAAALEwAACxMBAJqcGAAAAAd0SU1FB9wCBxILEdjZkwoAAAdESURBVFjDnZddbFTHFcd/M9f75V2vlw+bAMqCHYysUkXNRyHEEpRQsEj7gOzUgEiJkgdHSlAek5cAolUlniIRUFJQnnCqhDQ4ICWNBXESoKKpIlAIpaCYQmRsYj5sr3e93nv3zp3pw91ddsE2hJGOZnfm3PP/z5kzc84I7qPlOjuJ7N8PQH779rWyunoFwWCTCAQiSAlK5XDdPm3bJwJvvnkUwN66lfDevfe0LaabTK1fT+LwYca3bHnCikR2yurq31mLFiGSSUQiAaEQQgiMUpBKofv70ZcvoycmPtO53I7q9947ne7oIP7RRw9G4Nazz86vCga7AnV1q0KrVhk5d64Q4+OYTAYRDEI4DEKAUhjXRdTUQDSKvnbNOF9/LdTNm1/pfP6PiSNHBn82gaHVqzutQGBfTWurCdXXC/P99wjPgxkzoK7O72MxsCywbRgbg1u3IJXCCIFYsoT80JDJ9vQI5bov1x89un8yHDnZ4NWWlr0yGt03s72d0OnTgq4uxE8/+ZOWBVL6YlkQCFT+NwZx/Tp8+CHBs2dF7XPPIaLRfYMrV+65LwL/e/LJnVYi8ersp59GvP02nD8PWoNSvngeuC7k8/7Ks1lwHP+/Uv6c1r5cuIB4911mt7RgxeNbf1y2bOeUW3CuuZlAILAsEIt9s6C1FfHOO8hg0Hf1rFnwzDMwMuK7PZGAeBwiEX/l+bxPZHQUmpr87Th82NcfHsY4Dqazk/6eHvLZ7FOe6/77F+fPV3ogMzoq3VzuxEOtrcbbvRuTyfircRzf6LZt8NJLkMtBOg2pVAmA0VFfHnkENmyAzk5oaYHxcYzrQiaDt3s3c9asMWpi4sRwJlPCtYo/Xq2v/8uMpUt/Ezt1SpgrV5BCIKSEpUsR778PxsCcOdDQAF9+6W+F49wmtHgxbN7s6wGsWAE3biBOnsTk8+ixMUQ6LbxHH7W8oaHgX0dGekse+D3gOs4bs+rrcc+cwQDadTGPPYbo7vaNCuH3TU3w+uswNAQ3b8L169DYCM8/f1uvqLtjB+aVV9COgwHUmTPMrKvDdZw3flVc+fHZs/nnnDkb/9vaalLNzSYFZhyMvWiRMcYYo7WZtF26ZExbmzFvvTWlni6MOWAmwKTBpJubzcV168ypefM2nqyv90l8lUh8OrBli74OZqSgOFFba9SBA2badvr0PcHzDz9sJgqLSoG5BWbwhRf08ZkzPy1tgcrn14WUEh5QkrEx8i++iD5yZOqr8vHHb7u9rBljEIC7YAHe1avocrtAWCmhHGcNgPxHJFJjJRJS9fXhAapc2fOw16/HO3ZsmmwyNbjq78eDuwioH35AxuPBnkikWmqt51uxGM7ISAm8nIQGnLVr0V98cc/MVgR3kklU2cpVmU0XcEZGsGpr0bBQGq1jxrJQjnOXoiqTiTVr8Hp7p0+tQmA3NKAGBiq+LbfpAcpxQEo8raulp3VW2TZKCFRBKV/4yC0jIjo6sFavvqcXAh98gLKsuwiU21RC4No2Rqms1J43aI+O4oXDFYBumVgdHUQPHrx9yUzTrOXLqe7tRYVCFTbKbepIhNzwMK7W/bIN0rlUSnvRaEkhXxAXCHR0UFsEF+J+CigCK1dS88knqGi0ZKvcpqquxh4bc9uNycpCRurJWZZx7lh5eNMm6g4exExx1HQ2OyWJ8Lp1zDx0CFfKCpt5IGtZBjgGILv9y6Ark0oJT8oSUxuYvWtXKbgmi/ZrixeTK5wOc8f2GGOobm1l3uefY5d5QElJJpUSErq6i+m4GzCgH2pqEm5fH1VAFRCIxfjluXMEFy68C/xyMokaGABg3scfE2tv9+cKZI0xmIkJ/tPYiHPjRikYA01NDPb1GQmyrXgTtvm2d00oVRED9vg43y1eTL4AVAS/kEySHRgo6f24cSOjXV13gX+XTJK9cQOnbP/HlULArrY7C5JusDRkZzQ2Bt3Ll0VVgV2xf+LSJUKNjZxNJnEHBhB3FpTBIAsPHGDWhg142Synk0nyIyMVN2CgocEMX7mSlxBt84cqCAA8JcPhf4WjUbzh4RK4BQRrawnNnUvu4sUK8GJvACMES3p6uLBpUwW4BqxZs8hls3i2vRz4pm2qqrgbdlbFYtullOh0GqugJMuqFznJx6YgXmG8CKwBKx7H1RpvfPxPbbDjnmX5IdhjRSJbZSiESqUqSIgyYRICxbNQzANViQSe4+Dlcnva4bX7fhd0Q6ewrH0yHjduJiNQqoLAZB4o9hqgqopATY3x0mlhPO/lNtj/s19G3TDfwN+scHilCYWMsm3hOc60WyBDIarCYSMcR3i2fVzA5jYYfKCnWbH9HX4t4c8S1sh4XOZzOWTxWeafO7RtE4pE8NJpreGYhm1/gG8f9HEqgQAQBsICwsaPwdBr8NsGWBaFBgmRwn7bGbhyBb7dC72AI0Ab/0KdKFysxYR43x4QhcCvKpAJFggFC+PFuJSFeKMs6dnF2qOsHNCTgfwfl5gsFvMgXIgAAAAASUVORK5CYII=");
        }
    };
}());
```

Comment: At the very least for option 1) you can use tools to bundle all your js into one minified file when loading onto the live site, and for test sites leave them separated for debuggin.

Comment: @rlemon putting images in base 64 is not simpler. Editing them makes it harder and there is the whole separation of concerns. IMHO it works well for small images or in situations where multiple requests are very very bad. Usually you just have one sprite image and your css looks after the rest. Having to decide where to put images or changing css is normal, this is what css was made for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Embedding images inside the source makes the images hard to maintain but there is almost always a trade for performance.

Here are a few tips after reviewing your code.

## 1) Use `Notifier` as a namespace.

The module design pattern doesn't go well with this project because Notifier doesn't have anything to hide.
Also you should create functions inside the closure, then attach the functions to the returned object literal.

## 2) Expose as much as possible to prevent hard-coding values.

What are you hiding the `config` variable? It's best if you attach it as a property to `Notifier`.
Also attach the image values to the config variable. 
Try something like this, `Notifier.config.imgs.warning`.

Old Code:

```
//...
info: function(message, title) {
    this.notify(message, title, "data:image/png;base64,i...");
},
//...
```

New Code:

```
Notifier.config = {
    //...
    imgs = {
        //...
        info: "data:image/png;base64,i..."
        //...
    }
    //...
};
//...
info: function(message, title) {
    this.notify(message, title, Notifier.config.imgs.info );
},
//...
```

## 3) Rewrite `fade_out`

The function `fade_out` contains multiple problems:

- `fade_out` is a recursive functions without a break condition, meaning this function is never ending once called.
  To fix this, add a simple condition to that will clear the timeout or return from the function.
- Too many `if` and `else` conditions are used. Reduce the logic to simplify to conditions.
- `setTimeout` is used to create an interval, when setInterval is more appropriate.

Old Code:

```
var fade_out = function(element) {
    if (element.style.opacity && element.style.opacity > 0.05) {
        element.style.opacity = element.style.opacity - 0.05;
    } else if (element.style.opacity && element.style.opacity <= 0.1) {
        if (element.parentNode) {
            element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
        }
    } else {
        element.style.opacity = 0.9;
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
        fade_out.apply(this, [element]);
    }, 1000 / 30);
};
```

New Code:

```
fade_out = function (element) {
    if (!element || !element.style) {
        return;
    }
    var fn = function(){
        if (0.05 < element.style.opacity) {
            element.style.opacity -= 0.05;
            return;
        }
        element.style.opacity = 0;
        if( element.parentNode ){
            element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
        }
        clearInterval(t);
    }, t = setInterval(fn, 1000 / 30);
};
```

## 4) Expose the events

For further flexible, provide access to the mouse events by attaching them to the `config` or `Notifier` object.

Old Code:

```
//...
notification.onclick = function() {
    this.style.display = 'none';
};
//...
```

New code:

```
//...
Notifier.event.onclick = function () {
    this.style.display = 'none';
};
//...
notification.onclick = Notifier.event.onclick;
//...
```

## 5) Split up functions that are 8 - 12 lines into smaller units

`notify` has high complexity because it's handling too much. Try to abstract the logic into smaller units that only perform one task.

Old Code:

```
notify: function(message, title, image) {

        var notification = document.createElement('div');
        apply_styles(notification, config.box_styles);

        notification.onmouseover = function() {
            apply_styles(this, config.box_styles_hover);
        };
        notification.onmouseout = function() {
            apply_styles(this, config.box_styles);
        };
        //... more code
        //... more code
        setTimeout(function() {
            fade_out(notification);
        }, config.default_timeout);
    },
```

New Code:

```
Notifier.notify = function (message, title, image) {
    var notification = Notifier.element.createNotification(image);
    notification.appendChild(Notifier.element.getTextNotice(title, message));
    Notifier.container.insertBefore(notification, Notifier.container.firstChild);
    setTimeout(function () {
        Notifier.element.fade_out(notification);
    }, Notifier.config.default_timeout);
};
```

## 6) Create a setup function that auto-starts

It's good to have an `setup` or `init` function with a script that's more than 50 lines of code.

Additional code:

```
Notifier.setup = (function () {
    Notifier.element.apply_styles(Notifier.container, Notifier.config.container_styles);
    document.body.appendChild(Notifier.container);
}());
```

### Final Result:

```
var Notifier = {
    container : document.createElement('div'),
    element : {},
    event : {}
};
Notifier.config = {
    default_timeout : 5000,
    container : Notifier.container,
    container_styles : {
        position : "fixed",
        zIndex : 99999,
        right : "12px",
        top : "12px"
    },
    box_styles : {
        cursor : "pointer",
        padding : "12px 18px",
        margin : "0 0 6px 0",
        backgroundColor : "#000",
        opacity : 0.8,
        color : "#fff",
        font : "normal 13px 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif",
        borderRadius : "3px",
        boxShadow : "#999 0 0 12px",
        width : "300px"
    },
    box_styles_hover : {
        opacity : 1,
        boxShadow : "#000 0 0 12px"
    },
    title_styles : {
        fontWeight : "700"
    },
    text_styles : {
        display : "inline-block",
        verticalAlign : "middle",
        width : "240px",
        padding : "0 12px"
    },
    icon_styles : {
        display : "inline-block",
        verticalAlign : "middle",
        height : "36px",
        width : "36px"
    },
    imgs : {
        error : "data:image/png;base64,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",
        info : "data:image/png;base64,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",
        success : "data:image/png;base64,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",
        warning : "data:image/png;base64,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"
    }
};
Notifier.element.apply_styles = function (element, style_object) {
    for (var prop in style_object) {
        if (style_object.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            element.style[prop] = style_object[prop];
        }
    }
};
Notifier.element.fade_out = function (element) {
    if (!element || !element.style) {
        return;
    }
    var fn = function(){
        if (0.05 < element.style.opacity) {
            element.style.opacity -= 0.05;
            return;
        }
        element.style.opacity = 0;
        if( element.parentNode ){
            element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
        }
        clearInterval(t);
    }, t = setInterval(fn, 1000 / 30);
};
Notifier.element.getTextNotice = function (title, message) {
    var text = document.createElement('div'),
    title_text = document.createElement('div'),
    message_text = document.createElement('div');
    Notifier.element.apply_styles(text, Notifier.config.text_styles);
    if (title) {
        Notifier.element.apply_styles(title_text, Notifier.config.title_styles);
        title_text.appendChild(document.createTextNode(title));
        text.appendChild(title_text);
    }
    if (message) {
        message_text.appendChild(document.createTextNode(message));
        text.appendChild(message_text);
    }
    return text;
};
Notifier.element.createNotification = function (image) {
    var el = document.createElement('div'),
    icon = document.createElement('img');
    icon.src = image;
    Notifier.element.apply_styles(icon, Notifier.config.icon_styles);
    el.appendChild(icon);
    Notifier.element.apply_styles(el, Notifier.config.box_styles);

    el.onmouseover = Notifier.event.onmouseover;
    el.onmouseout = Notifier.event.onmouseout;
    el.onclick = Notifier.event.onclick;
    return el;
};
Notifier.event.onmouseover = function () {
    Notifier.element.apply_styles(this, Notifier.config.box_styles_hover);
};
Notifier.event.onmouseout = function () {
    Notifier.element.apply_styles(this, Notifier.config.box_styles);
};
Notifier.event.onclick = function () {
    this.style.display = 'none';
};
Notifier.setup = (function () {
    Notifier.element.apply_styles(Notifier.container, Notifier.config.container_styles);
    document.body.appendChild(Notifier.container);
}());
// original API
Notifier.notify = function (message, title, image) {
    var notification = Notifier.element.createNotification(image);
    notification.appendChild(Notifier.element.getTextNotice(title, message));
    Notifier.container.insertBefore(notification, Notifier.container.firstChild);
    setTimeout(function () {
        Notifier.element.fade_out(notification);
    }, Notifier.config.default_timeout);
};
Notifier.info = function (message, title) {
    Notifier.notify(message, title, Notifier.config.imgs.info);
};
Notifier.warning = function (message, title) {
    Notifier.notify(message, title, Notifier.config.imgs.warning);
};
Notifier.success = function (message, title) {
    Notifier.notify(message, title, Notifier.config.imgs.success);
};
Notifier.error = function (message, title) {
    Notifier.notify(message, title, Notifier.config.imgs.error);
};
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Lpuj2/

Comment: Wow! thanks for the feedback (this is what I get for not checking back in a week :P) I just got your pull request I will review it when I get home from work :)

Answer (score 6):

Site loading performance depends on the number of HTTP request in many cases. The less of them, the better. This rule justify your reasoning to keep everything in one file that is being loaded with one request.

There are, however, two things that should also be considered:

1. Caches. In normal case, your CSS and image files will be cached and
   this should prevent browser from doing too much requests. This, of
   course, needs some server side configuration but if anybody cares
   about performance, ensuring proper cache configuration is probably
   one of the most important things anyway. Of course javascript file
   can be cached too but it's not always possible so it just depends on
   your workload.
2. Dynamic change of styles and DOM. When all the styles are in single
   file,  browser may read, parse and apply them all at the same time,
   causing only one reflow. When you set them individually, it may do
   reflow each time you do the change. Now, in most cases, browsers
   will queue some changes before doing reflow, letting changes to be
   applied in groups. But this is browser specific and you have no
   control over this. Since you are changing styles using properties,
   you are actually doing a lot of small changes. It is why it is
   generally faster to switch CSS classes instead of changing
   individual properties but you can't do this with your approach. You
   can, however, use CSS classes as I mentioned still having whole CSS
   embedded in your code. Here's how:

   ```
   var style = document.createElement('style');
   style.type = 'text/css';
   style.innerHTML = "YOUR WHOLE CSS";
   document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
   ```

   Just replace "YOUR WHOLE CSS" with your values. This way whole CSS is loaded at once, you have CSS classes and can apply them easily at once instead of changing each property one by one.

All this is theoretical. You may get different performances on different browsers (or even on different versions of one browser) sine each of them implement some other optimisations techniques. So the only proper way of optimising your scripts is to try and measure. On as many browsers as you can.

Answer (score 3):

A few observations:

1. If a specific part of the file is supposed to change a lot, then refer to Krzysztof Adamski's answer.
2. You also need to look at the size of base64 images: storing an image in base64 takes more space than in a file since (about 33%). For large images, it can be a problem. This is where CSS sprites can help: you only use one file to store multiple iamges.
3. If your project is going to get bigger, then you should use the module pattern and a tool like RequireJS to manage depedencies. This is explained in the [Learning JavaScript Design Patterns](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/) online book.

My conclusion is that for this example it's OK: it's small enough to be easy to understand and edit, you will only need one HTTP request which is great for performance, and it's easy to send to your users (eg. other developers).